# Java Error: 'Throw new Exception not Supported'

Tags: java, junit, exception, throw

I looked around and am a little confused if it is working or not. The result while debugging gives me the impression that it fails.

```
Statement 'throw new SessionTimeoutException("Session Timeout"); ' not supported
```

I am running a test case in Junit and have made many using exceptions previously already however they are implemented in the same manner as the method below at.

```
private void checkSessionTimeout(HtmlPage page) throws SessionTimeoutException {
```

I am new to Exceptions and do not understand why it only errors at runtime during the test.

My test runs and fails in the method inside the if statement

```
private void checkSessionTimeout(HtmlPage page) throws SessionTimeoutException {
    HtmlDivision imgDivElement = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@class='border']");
    HtmlDivision errorDivElement = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@class='error']");

    String imgUrl = imgDivElement.getFirstElementChild().getAttribute("src");
    String errorMessage = errorDivElement.getTextContent().trim();

    if(page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString().contains(imgUrl) && page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString().contains(errorMessage)){
        throw new SessionTimeoutException("Session Timeout");
    }
}
```

At this line:  **throw new SessionTimeoutException("Session Timeout");**

```
package com.cantShow;

import com.cantShow.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.cantShow.TimeoutInformation;
import com.cantShow.AbstractScraperTest;
import com.cantShow.scrape.Scraper;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.cantShow.SessionTimeoutException;

public class ScraperTest extends ScraperTest<HtmlPage, SessionTimoutClassWithGettersSetters> {

@Override
protected Scraper<HtmlPage, SessionTimoutClassWithGettersSetters> getScraper() {
    return new Scraper();
}

@Test
public void scrape() throws Exception {
    SessionTimoutClassWithGettersSettersresult = testScraper("/scrape/timeout-session.html",
            "https://cantShow.html");

    details(result, "imgs/error.png","Your session has timed out. You will need to log back in to continue shopping.");
}

private static void details(SessionTimoutClassWithGettersS setterstimeoutInformation, String errorImgUrl, String errorMsg){
    assertEquals(errorImgUrl, sessionTimoutClassWithGettersSetters.getErrorImageUrl());
    assertEquals(errorMsg, sessionTimoutClassWithGettersSetters.getErrorMessage());
}
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
com.cantShow.Scraper.checkSessionTimeout(Scraper.java:28)
atcom.cantShow.Scraper.Scraper.scrape(Scraper.java:16)
at com.cantShow.Scraper.Scraper.scrape(Scraper.j va:12)
at com.cantShow.Scraper.ScrapeService.scrapeString(ScrapeService.java:406)
at com.cantShow.Scraper.AbstractScraperTest.testScraper(AbstractScraperTest.java:32)
at com.cantShow.Scraper.ScraperTest.scrape(ScraperTest.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I have looked at other posts on Stack Overflow however could not find one like this for Java.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. What is that method? Is it part of your test, or is it the production code that the test verifies? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead, precisely?

Comment: Production code that the test verifies

Comment: I expect for it to throw the exception because it is true.But I am not sure if it is working because it fails and tests are suppose to pass

Comment: What is the import for `SessionTimeoutException`? Is it in the classpath for junit test? If the test is failing is there a stacktrace?

Comment: import com.cantShow.SessionTimeoutException; There is a stack trace and what do you mean ' in the class path for the junit test?

Comment: So, your test fails instead of passing, and the production code is doing the right thing. So the test code is not correct. So, if you want help, post the test code.

Comment: I think the test code is correct, I added the stack trace. I will add Test code in a moment

Comment: Your code is throwing exception in `checkSessionTimeout` but if it is not handled in `ScrapeService.scrapeString` or caught in `AbstractScraperTest.testScraper` then it would throw exception in the test and your test will fail.

Comment: Could you give an example as an answer and explain? And i will try your answer as soon as I get home. Thanks I appreciate it I am fairly confused.

Comment: I cannot give you example without knowing your code. All I can say is if the exception thrown from `ScrapeService.scrapeString` is valid in this scenario then it can't possibly return a value because it is throwing an exception so your test needs to check the validity of the exception by available means in junit. However if `ScrapeService.scrapeString` is supposed to catch this exception and return a string then your production code is wrong and junit is right.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test that the Exception is thrown you have to catch it and verify that it is the right Exception.

```
@Test
public void scrape() throws Exception {
    boolean exceptionHappend = false;
    try {
        SessionTimoutClassWithGettersSettersresult = 
            testScraper("/scrape/timeoutsession.html", "https://cantShow.html");
    } catch (SessionTimeoutException e) {
        exceptionHappend = true;
    }

    assertTrue(exceptionHappend);
    details(result, "imgs/error.png","Your session has timed out. You will need to log back in to continue shopping.");
}
```